# Laravel/Mysql - Specified key was too long Permanent Solution

Tags: php, laravel

I guess most Laravel developers know about atomic bomb that explodes when connecting to a MySQL database.

`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

This happens every time i start a new project and i do not want that. is there a permanent way around. I dont want to keep doing this at every installation of laravel.

Comment: What is the version of mysql you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As per the laravel offical document, If you are using MySql version above `5.7.7` and MariaDB version above `10.2.2` you don't need to do the below step manually and each and every time when you install Laravel fresh project.

If you are using MySql version above `5.7.7` and MariaDB version above `10.2.2` older then, then you need to do the following thing in order to resolve this error

> In a simple language, Update your MySql or MariaDB version, to avoid
>   this exception completely

Just go and edit `AppServiceProvider.php` file and increase the string length inside your `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //increase string length
```

and add the following line in the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

You can find on below path `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

for more you can take reference from [here](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

> If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or
>   MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually
>   configure the default string length generated by migrations in order
>   for MySQL to create indexes for them.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand this. My only problem is i do this every time. Is there not a way we can fix this once and for all and forget about this bug?

Comment: I have found following line in laravel doc " If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. "

Comment: How do i configure the default string?

Comment: @AdeyemiOlusegun If you read the above answer I have mentioned each thing to avoid the exception kindly check that

Comment: Same thing i was running from, ok! Thank, i sincerely appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your AppServiceProvider.php file which exists in app/providers folder you will find a function boot where you have to add the followings:

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
and you have add the following at the top of the file:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```